# Are there any papers arguing against vaccination in French?

Tags: vaccination

### Disclaimer: This question is NOT about challenging the safety or efficacy of vaccines. It is only asking for tips on providing credible references that may show harmful effects of vaccination, if any.

In my French class, we were asked to debate an issue in current events. My topic is vaccines in children or adults.

The challenging part is that I was assigned to argue **against** vaccination, and I have to back up my arguments with credible sources (not blogs) that are in French. Hopefully some of you could point me towards some links to articles or research papers in French.

### Please avoid discussion on safety and efficacy of vaccines, including local and global policies on their use. I just need help with this topic for my French class

Comment: What about looking into positive studies and say that all distributions have negative-side tails that cause death _etc_. In **real** science there are studies like "X is good for you", only "in p% cases X helps to increase Z by q%". Take (1-p)% cases and use that as an argument

Comment: *there are _no_ studies like X is good for you

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you pick this topic or did your teacher?

Comment: Strangely, it seems that all of the debates about science aren't actually based in science at all. Vaccines, evolution, global warming, etc…

Comment: Maybe instead of a direct approach you can find arguments on why death by disease isn't so bad after all?  But seriously, you're not going to find much in biology; you might be better off looking for non-scientific arguments.  For example, some religions view disease as an expression of divine will and discourage medical treatment.

Comment: I guess you can find interesting material following the links in this article: http://rougeole-epidemiologie.overblog.com/2015/05/vaccin-dt-polio-faut-il-signer-la-petition-joyeux-ipsn.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks evidence for a wrong claim. There are no evidences yet for vaccines having bad effects. This question is also likely to attract anti-vaccination supporters who may claim this post as a support for their cause.

Comment: @WYSIWYG so when people get disease after&due to vaccination it is OK? science is about measuring real effects, not saying that something is bad or good.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - asking for references for *any* claim should be on-topic. Whether it has proven correct or incorrect. Stuff being considered correct now is proven incorrect tomorrow. Isn't that science? Moreover, the Wakefield study  is an important study, as it stands example for total non-sense making it into one of the most respected journals worldwide.

Comment: @aandreev and AliceD I am not questioning the scientific process. I am just saying that the way the question is worded, it is likely to get into controversies. We can always say no it doesn't happen like that as per the research till now and many of you have said that. Questions about specific formulations of drugs/vaccines are fine. This post needs to be protected if not closed and even then there may be people with enough rep who will come up with theories. We can't keep moderating it forever.

Comment: You could find credible sources arguing against specific vaccines but not against vaccination in general. That's like looking for credible sources arguing that the earth is flat.

Comment: @terdon: That would actually be my strategy: find many credible sources arguing against several specific vaccinations, and paint the pro-vaccination crowd as zealots trying to stuff vaccines down everybody's veins.

Comment: Not an answer, but just a hint -- I know that there's an angle that condemns vaccines because they (some of them) contain aluminium compounds, which in turn is claimed to cause Alzheimer's disease. Highly controversial and certainly not my POV, but perhaps this provides you with a couple more keywords.

Comment: can we probably add a disclaimer that question is not for discussing vaccines, but for providing credible references that show harmful effects of vaccination?

Comment: There is **no** scientific dispute that modern vaccines are brilliant. The anti-vaxxers rely only on [pseudo scientific fear mongering](http://drtenpenny.com) and [ludicrous, offensive campaigns](http://www.theguardian.com/society/2015/apr/23/campaign-comparing-vaccination-rprepulsive-health-minister-says) to further their profiteering. The only (off topic) debate to be had is whether or not one has the right to refuse vaccination for non-medical reasons and (rather selfishly in my opinion) rely on herd immunity, which is very risky for the individual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wish you good luck, as 99.99% of the anecdotal claims out there that conclude vaccination is bad are based on unfounded rumors.

Note that much of the negative public opinion is based on a fraudulent (and retracted) paper by [*Wakefield in The Lancet (1998)*](http://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736%2897%2911096-0/abstract). Unfortunately for you, however, it is in English.

My French is a bit rusty, but if you go to [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com.au/schhp) and type in a search term like **vaccination results in autism** (*les résultats de la vaccination dans l'autisme*) or *Wakefield vaccination autisme* something might pop up in French that advocates against vaccination.

Comment: I do wonder if Wakefield regrets the damage he has done. 5% of children under 7 in California are not vaccinated. Measles is a preventable condition! One I've never had to endure!

Answer (score 4):

The Wakefield study has [collapsed as fraud](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/02/us/a-discredited-vaccine-studys-continuing-impact-on-public-health.html), and there are no credible sources that make persuasive scientific arguments against being vaccinated in today's world -- not even in French.

Comment: did you mean "in English"?

Comment: @MarchHo I meant "in French". Apparently certain types of humor fail to translate well to the written word.

Answer (score 4):

You will not find good, credible sources arguing against vaccination. However, spewing nonsense is not necessary for winning your debate. You can collect good, credible sources arguing against specific vaccinations and use them to paint the opposing side as pro-vaccination zealots who unquestioningly want to stuff vaccines down everybody's veins.

Vaccines, like other treatments, have to be approved by health authorities, and therefore, the possible side effects are being studied in clinical trials. All you have to do is find a few cases where there side effects were a bit more severe than anticipated.

A good start for your research could therefore be publications about the risks of vaccination. On Google Scholar, "risques vaccination" brings up hits like [Risk-Benefit assessment of hepatitis B vaccination in France (in French)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0248866305002742) that can give you a good basis for gathering material against vaccination.

Comment: @AliceD: I reverted some of your changes to keep the original meaning of my post. If you feel the first paragraph remains problematic, I'd rather take it out completely.

Comment: If you don't mind - I've taken it out. As it was previously, it could have lead to anti-vaccination people (ab)using your answer in favor of their stand point. OPs question is kind of problematic in that it may lead to endless debate

Comment: @AliceD: I tried another version that states why am trying to give the OP what he needs rather than what he seems to be asking for.

Answer (score -1):

The only angle I can think of that isn't "Haha, I can't believe these people are allowed to vote" is that the enemy we know is better than the enemy we do not know.

I see no reason why the classic argument of selection pressure doesn't apply. (See Warfrin(spelling?) resistance in rats, the resistant rats required more vitamin-k, thus more time out in the sun, so in a warfrin free environment are at a disadvantage, but thrive in an environment with warfrin)

Unfortunately (fortunately) evidence doesn't really support that, in fact we have *eradicated* several diseases already entirely and nothing replaced them.

(Long comment sorry)

By the way! Do tell us some of the arguments that come up!

Comment: I don't think the resistance angle helps much here, but if one wanted to pursue it, this question is relevant: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30166/why-vaccines-do-not-cause-bacterial-resistance/

Comment: @Corvus indeed, no doctor is going to say "Let them die!" (side note: "overprescription of antibiotics" is a hot topic in the UK because bacterial resistance is actually becoming a problem! However that's not vaccination)

Comment: Also @Corvus thanks for that link, I was wondering while I was writing!